# Bootstrap lot of space between h1 and h2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a structure made on twitter Bootstrap which you can see here:
http://codepen.io/DiV666/pen/zBxdmw

The problem is that there is lot of space between the rows containing the h1 (TITLE) and h2 (Subtitle). This space depends on the left menu, if you remove or add options, this space becomes larger or smaller.

To fix it I set `overflow: hidden;` in `#page-content`, but I do not know if this is the best way.

Can someone help?

Thank You.

Comment: did you clear margin of h1? As  h1 has by default margin top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the `.row:after`. Just set it to initial, otherwise it inherits the table display from its parent:

```
.container-fluid .row:after{
  display: initial;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, had another problem with zindex in col-* { float:left } and this has also fixed, I could not click buttons. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` into .row class

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **Internal style** as below:

```
 #page-content  .container-fluid .row::after
 {
     display: initial ;
 }
 #page-content  .container-fluid::after
 {
     display: initial ;
 }
```

If it not works assign **!important**;

Answer (score 0):

Put both tags in the same row:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
       <h2>Subtitle</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAXkoJ

If you want a fixed sidebar so it didn't depend of the content of `page-content`, made it position fixed:

```
#page-sidebar {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
  position:fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAZyQE